# Divide two column values in SQL and insert result in new column

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table called Images with two columns named as width and height. I want to divide the values of both columns as width/height for each record in table and insert results into a new column called aspect ratio.

I have watched some links but not making even basic sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont store calculated values separately; you can get them in `select` query everytime. Still, if you want them as a separate column; look at Generated Columns. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with the below sql

```
update Images set aspect_ratio = width/height
```